# SFINAE не работает :(

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, c++14

Почему не компилируется?

```
template <size_t x, typename value_type>
class A {
    std::enable_if_t<x == 1, value_type> operator()() { return 1; }

    std::enable_if_t<x != 1, value_type> operator()() { return 2; }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

SFINAE работает на уровне выведения аргументов шаблона функции, но Ваши функции (операторы) не являются шаблонными, поэтому разговора о SFINAE быть не может в принципе — ему тут неоткуда взяться. При любых раскладах у Вас в классе всегда будут 2 функции, одна из которых *может* быть валидна, а вторая, на контрасте с первой, будет невалидной.

Но это если мы сделаем обе функции шаблонными, добавив некий фиктивный параметр шаблона. В текущей же редакции код просто-напросто невалиден в любом случае в силу того, что перегрузка нешаблонных функций по возвращаемому значению невозможна т.к. возвращаемый тип не является частью сигнатуры оной.

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор запрещает перегрузки с одинаковыми прототипами **несмотря на SFINAE**. Так что используйте вместо него обычное условие внутри функции.

```
template <size_t x, typename value_type>
class A {
    value_type operator()() {
        return (x == 1) ? 1 : 2;
    }
};
```

Любой более-менее современный компилятор оптимизирует условия с участием констант (к которым относится и шаблонный параметр `x`).

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE работает только для шаблонов (когда есть template непосредственно для сущности, для которой применяется SFINAE). Попробуйте так:

```
template <size_t x, typename value_type>
class A {
   template<class Enable = std::enable_if_t<x == 1>>
   value_type operator()() { return 1; }

   template<class Enable = std::enable_if_t<x != 1>>
   value_type operator()() { return 2; }
};
```

Еще вариант, можно использовать частичную специализацию шаблона для класса

```
template <size_t x, typename value_type>
class A {
   value_type operator()() { return 2; }
};

template <typename value_type>
class A <1, value_type> {
   value_type operator()() { return 1; }
};
```

Comment: У Вас первый вариант работоспособен?

Comment: @alexolut, не работает, но можно схитрить https://godbolt.org/g/8nIk0I

Answer (score 1):

В 17 стандарте появится `compile time if` - именно то, что нужно в этой ситуации :)

Comment: Если бы ещё все могли его на практике использовать... А Astra Linux, например, сейчас доступен только gcc-4.7, и это в версии этого года.